# Sequential composition of JS promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I came across the following example about sequential composition of promises on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Composition):

> Sequential composition is possible using some clever JavaScript:

```
[func1, func2, func3].reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve())
.then(result3 => { /* use result3 */ });
```

> Basically, we reduce an array of asynchronous functions down to a promise chain equivalent to: Promise.resolve().then(func1).then(func2).then(func3);
>
> This can be made into a reusable compose function, which is common in functional programming:

```
const applyAsync = (acc,val) => acc.then(val);
const composeAsync = (...funcs) => x => funcs.reduce(applyAsync, Promise.resolve(x));
...
const transformData = composeAsync(func1, func2, func3);
const result3 = transformData(data);
```

What I did not understand is why they wrote that the last line of the above code sets `result3` with `transformData(data)`, because `transformData(data)` returns itself a promise.

Shouldn't the last line be:

```
transformData(data).then((result3) => {
   // Do something with result3 ...
});
```

?

The documentation goes on with:

> In ECMAScript 2017, sequential composition can be done more simply with async/await:

```
let result;
for (const f of [func1, func2, func3]) {
  result = await f(result);
}
/* use last result (i.e. result3) */
```

Here `result` is indeed the result of `func3` (the successful resolution of the promise leading to `result3`).

Thank you for your attention.